# Why do I keep getting this indexing error?

Tags: java, arrays, loops, indexing

I keep getting StringIndexOutOfBoundsException. I'm trying to take a String and replace each letter with the one after it, then return the new manipulated String. For example, "Hey", is "Ifz".

I've tried changing the indexing but nothing is working.

```
String change = "";
char[] alpha =  {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'};


 for(int i = 0; i < alpha.length; i++) {

    if(str.charAt(i) == alpha[i]) {
        change += alpha[i+1] + "";
    }


    }

    return change;

  } 

  public static void main (String[] args) {  
    // keep this function call here     
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print(LetterChanges(s.nextLine())); 
  }   

 Error Message:

 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException:    

String index out of range: 18
at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:658)
at Main.LetterChanges(Main.java:11)
at Main.main(Main.java:25)
```

Comment: I have change += by the way.

Comment: The exact error says:

Comment: Error:
      Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 18
 at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:658)
 at Main.LetterChanges(Main.java:11)
 at Main.main(Main.java:25)

Comment: **change =+ str.charAt(i+1) + "";**       _Did you mean to put a "+=" here instead...?_

Comment: @learning It's best to place the information such as the error message into the question itself, rather than a comment, using the "edit" link, because that is part of your question.

Comment: @Cyber_Agent yes, it's supposed to be +=

Comment: Have you tried to debug the code?

Comment: @rgettman Thank you!

Comment: @JoakimDanielson yes

Comment: If your are going to be working against the string `Hey` then when your **for** loop iterates to the index 2 which happens to be the third character of `Hey` (H=0, e=1, y=2), what do you think will happen when this piece of code is encountered: `str.charAt(i+1)`? **i + 1** would be 3, there is no Index 3 for the String `Hey`.

Comment: Then you need to improve your debugging skills

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the length of `str` might be less than 26 (as you are iterating over the list alpha) so `str.charAt(i)` will throw the exception. If your string guarantees that it only consists of ASCII letters, then one way to implement it is:

```
String getChange(String str){
     StringBuilder change = new StringBuilder();
     for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++){
        char c = str.charAt(i);
        int nextCharPos ;
        if ('a' <= c && c <= 'z')
            nextCharPos = ((int) ('a')) + ((c - 'a') + 1) % 26;
        else if ('A' <= c && c <= 'Z')
            nextCharPos = ((int) ('A')) + ((c - 'A') + 1) % 26;
        else {
            change.append(c);
            continue;
        }
        char nextChar = (char)(nextCharPos);
        change.append(nextChar);
     }
     return change.toString();
}
```

Comment: @DevilsHnd It doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

1. if str is less than 26 (alpha.length) , then str.charAt(i) will give error.
2. alpha[i+1] , if i is 25 , then alpha[i+1] = alpha[26] which does not exist and again gives error

Answer (score 0):

```
private static String LetterChanges(String str) {
    String change = "";
    char[] alpha = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's',
            't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z' };

    for(int i = 0 ; i < str.length() ; i++) {
        change = change.concat(Character.toString(getNextChar(str.charAt(i), alpha)));
    }
    return change;
}

private static char getNextChar(char eachChar, char[] alpha) {
    int charIndex = -1;
    for(int i = 0 ; i < alpha.length ; i++) {
        if(alpha[i] == eachChar) {
            charIndex = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(charIndex != -1) {
        //To handle the last indexed char 
        if(charIndex == alpha.length-1) {
            return alpha[0];
        } else {
            return alpha[charIndex+1];
        }
    }
    //default for unknown character
    return '-';
}
```

This code limits the input string to the alpha array elements and anything outside the array will default to '-'. This code will also cycle the elements i.e. 'z' in the input  will be replaced by 'a'.